# Need help on Services definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, constructor, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

**These are my codes in Controller:**

```
 public class IdentityUserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<DatabaseContext> _um;
    private readonly SignInManager<DatabaseContext> _sm;
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {       
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login( Models.Person  lc)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             var result = await _sm.PasswordSignInAsync(lc.NationalCode, lc.Password, false, true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                TempData["LoggedUserCode"] = lc.NationalCode;
                ViewBag.LoggeduserDetails = lc.Name + " " + lc.Family;
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User or Password not valid");
        }
        return View(lc);
    }
```

}

**and these are codes in startup Configuration:**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source =. ; Initial Catalog = LeaveSheet; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true "));
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option => option.LoginPath = "/IdentityUser/Login");
    }
```

### **when I run it I get below error in login view after submit:**

***NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

- LeaveSheet.Controllers.IdentityUserController.Login(Person lc) in IdentityUserController.cs

  ```
              var result = await _sm.PasswordSignInAsync(lc.NationalCode, lc.Password, false, true);
  ```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
*

**would you please helping me **

Comment: Do you have the following constructor in your `DatabaseContext`? `public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
{ }`If not, please add it.

Comment: Any update about this case?

Comment: ***Hi Yinqiu   Thanks for reply ---- I added constructor which you suggested*** ---- **Now I got this error on run time when I call action Login** ---------   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[LeaveSheet.Models.Context.DatabaseContext]' while attempting to activate 'LeaveSheet.Controllers.IdentityUserController'.

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Comment: I suggest you to learn the [Identity in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: First,your DatabaseContext should inherit `IdentityDbContext`,then your controller should be `private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _um;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _sm;`,then in your startup should add `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>();`

Comment: Thanks , because this project is at the end of coding I don't want to change inheritance of DbContext from IdentityDbContext . I am beginner in MVC and I  didn't have enough knowledge of core so changing inheritance  will affect all of actions and .... process will be more complicated !

Comment: **Hi Yinqiu** I passed last error and now i got new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to change my database structure and implement Identity from base.